# Execute local script on remote host by passing remote host parameters on command line together with script arguments

Tags: bash, shell

is anybody aware if there is a syntax to pass a remote host parameters (user and IP/hostname) together with script arguments on local host and make it execute on the remote host?

I'm not meaning like this: `$ ssh user@remoteServer "bash -s" -- < /path/script.ssh -a X -b Y`

I want instead for the script to be able to be passed like this: `$/path/script.ssh user@remoteServer -a X -b Y`

But I'm not sure how to achieve, in the script, this kind of behaviour:

```
[...] script [...]

connect to user@remoteServer

[...] execute the script code (on the remote host) [...]

end of script
```

Any suggestion? Do I need to work this from another way instead?

**EDIT**

I've managed to make the script execute *something* after it connects via SSH, but I'm a bit as for why some commands are executed before they are passed to the remote host terminal; my code looks like this at the moment:

```
while getopts 'ha:u:d:s:w:c:' OPT; do
  case $OPT in
    a) host=$OPTARG;;
    u) user=$OPTARG ;;
    d) device=$OPTARG ;;
    s) sensor=$OPTARG ;;
    w) warn_thresh=$OPTARG ;;
    c) crit_thresh=$OPTARG ;;
    h) print_help
    *) printf "Wrong option or value\n"
        print_help
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# Check if host is reachable
if (( $# )); then
ssh ${user}@${host} < $0

# Check for sensor program or file
case $device in
        linux)  do things
        raspberry) do things
        amlogic)  do things
esac

# Read temperature information
case $device in
        linux)  do things
        raspberry)      do things
        amlogic)   do things
esac
                        
# Check for errors
if (())
then
  # Temperature above critical threshold
# Check for warnings
elif (())
then
  # Temperature above warning threshold
fi

# Produce Nagios output
printf [......]

fi
```

The script seemingly runs without issue, but I get no output.

Comment: Have the script make the ssh call?

Comment: Hi, the script code that has to be executed includes getopts, functions, cases and if statements: am I wrong in thinking that it would mess up something by simply doing something like: 
ssh user@remoteServer

[...] execute the script code as is now(on the remote host) [...]

Comment: As with any yes/no question, the real answer is *it depends*. Did you try it? Make a safe, simplified version and test it. Scan for things that need adjustment, but generally, the logic is sound.

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic example -

```
if (( $# ))          # if there are arguments 
then ssh "$1" < $0   # connect to the first and execute this script there
else whoami          # on the remote, there will be no args...
     uname -n        # if remote needs arguments, change the test condition
     date            # these statements can be as complex as needed
fi
```

My example script just takes a target system login as its first argument.
Run it with no args it outputs the data for the current system; use a login, it runs there.

If you have password-less logins with authorized keys it's very smooth, otherwise it will prompt you.

Just parse your arguments and behave accordingly. :)

If you *need* arguments on the remote, use a more complex test to decide which branch to take...

## Edit 2

I repeat: *If you need arguments on the remote, use a more complex test to decide which branch to take...*

```
while getopts 'ha:u:d:s:w:c:' OPT; do
  case $OPT in
    a) host=$OPTARG;;
    u) user=$OPTARG ;;
    d) device=$OPTARG ;;
    s) sensor=$OPTARG ;;
    w) warn_thresh=$OPTARG ;;
    c) crit_thresh=$OPTARG ;;
    h) print_help
    *) printf "Wrong option or value\n"
        print_help
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

# handoff to remote host
if [[ -n "$host" ]]
then scp "${user}@${host}:/tmp/" "$0"
     ssh "${user}@${host}" "/tmp/${0##*/} -d $device -s $sensor -w $warn_thresh -c $crit_thresh" 
     exit $?
fi

# if it gets here, we're ON the remote host, so code accordingly

# Check for sensor program or file
case $device in
        linux)  do things
        raspberry) do things
        amlogic)  do things
esac

# Read temperature information
case $device in
        linux)  do things
        raspberry)      do things
        amlogic)   do things
esac
                        
# Check for errors
if (())
then
  # Temperature above critical threshold
# Check for warnings
elif (())
then
  # Temperature above warning threshold
fi

# Produce Nagios output
printf [......]

fi
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example but I don't find much use of it since it's pretty basic; as I already mentioned the script after the SSH connection has cases, if statements and other tasks to perform.
I edited my question to show how the script as it looks now after the connession it's established.

Comment: @MonsieurMemons Great - and use the presented example to execute the script on remote host. `but I don't find much use` Why do you do not find any use of it? It allows to do exactly what you commented.

Comment: Hi, the reason why I don't find much use is clearly stated: `it's pretty basic`
The follow-up to the request with the actual code I'm trying to execute is, as stated always in the previous comment, in the edit of the original question; if you have any idea about the behavour I reported, please let me know.
Otherwise if you have no usefull suggestions please avoid commenting at all, I have no use for this kind of comments.

Comment: You missed the point of the example. The script checks whether there are arguments, and if there are, connect to the given remote host (`"$1"`) and passes *itself* as input - however complex *itself* might be, with "cases, if statements and other tasks". If you don't try things, why are you asking for help? If you did try it and it didn't work, what are the specific problems you encountered, so we can try to address them? "Pretty basic" is how you demonstate a "pretty basic" principle. I'll add some comment to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments and the additional explanation.
The problem is that I don't get any error, since I don't get any output at all.
I edited the code in the question to reflect the current state of the script.

Comment: Hi, I tried implement the code according to your last suggestions, but I'm still struggling.
If I write the SSH and argument passing line as you did, I get an hostname error: 
`ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.113 -d raspberry -s cpu -w 65 -c 75: Name or service not known`, while if i try for example to pass the arguments after the `$0` like `ssh -t "${user}@${host}" < $0 "-d $device -s $sensor -w $warn_thresh -c $crit_thresh"` i get an `-bash: line 83: host: unbound variable` error, because after the arguments are passed on script execution they are not passed again.

Comment: My mistake. Edited, with apologies - haven't had time to properly test.
Try this, if I get time I'll try to test myself and post with a more explicit example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply.
I see that you are suggesting to copy the file on the remote host, execute (and then eventually delete the tmp file): `then scp "${user}@${host}:/tmp/" "$0"
     ssh "${user}@${host}" "/tmp/${0##*/} -d $device -s $sensor -w $warn_thresh -c $crit_thresh" 
     exit $?
fi` but I was trying to avoid copying the file on the remote host, thus the original question of executing the local script remotely.
If in your opinion it has to come down to this, I'll start looking for an alternative way to achieve what I had in mind; nevertheless, thank you for your patience!

Comment: Ok, then... sounds like you're going to a lot of trouble to avoid a standard way of handling a pretty common problem. Good luck.